# how to get part after last dash in a string?

Tags: php

im new to php and i still dont know all, but here is what i need.

```
$entry= "Beyonce - Halo.mp3"
```

I seperate artist and title using this

```
"artist" => basename(strstr(" ".ucwords($entry), "- ", true )),
"title" => basename(substr(strrchr(ucwords($entry), "- "), 1), ".mp3"),
```

Can anyone tell me how to get the next text after " - " not from last, because in some cases we had song like this

```
$entry= "Beyonce - Halo - AlbumName.mp3"
```

and it get the "AlbumName" as title and its wrong!
How can i fix it? Thank you.

Comment: *and it get the "AlbumName" as title and its wrong* ? What does that mean that only `.mp3` is the file name or do you mean as artist? Also which pattern does the entry follows? Is the artist every time before the first `-`?

Comment: Um...why not use the ID3 tags from inside the mp3?  There is a library in PHP for doing that.

Comment: This thing [ (strrchr(ucwords($entry), "- "), 1) ], delete all text in $entry till "- "
So the results will be 
" Halo " but when $entry is with two minuses like this " Beyonce - Halo - AlbumName it show me the AlbumName as title. so i need a php query or how to say, that delete the text from first to last, not from Last to first.

Answer (score 0):

The title of your post is a bit confusing because I don't see anything about directories in your post, but I'm assuming you're looking at files on the filesystem, and you want to separate out things like the artist and song name based on either the file name or the directory they are contained in.

That being said, you can try out the php `explode()` function!

So you might use it like this:

`$array_of_piece = explode('-', $song_title);`

then you'd end up with an array consisting of pieces like:

`('Beyonce ', ' Halo ', ' Albumname.mp3')`

You could also split on `' - '` to get rid of some of the white space as well.